# How to validate a range of date by comparing those using php?

Tags: php, date, conditional-statements

I want to show validation errors

1. if the check out date is older than check in date.
2. if the check in date is equal to today tomorrow or day after tomorrow add
   error message.
3. if the check in and check out dates are same.
4. if the check out date is at least not newer than a day of check in date.

for these purpose I've created some variables.

```
$checkin_booking_period = $_POST["checkin_booking_period"];
    $checkout_booking_period = $_POST["checkout_booking_period"];
        $today = date("m.d.y");
        $dateTimestamp1 = strtotime($checkin_booking_period);
        $dateTimestamp2 = strtotime($checkout_booking_period);
        $tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+1, date("y"));
        $day_after_tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+2, date("y"));
```

and my condition statements are:

```
//check out date must be newer than check in date.
        if ($dateTimestamp1 > $dateTimestamp2) {
            //Blank string, add error to $errors array.        
            $errors['checkout_booking_period'] = "check out date must be newer than check in date!";
        }               
        if (($dateTimestamp1 = $tomorrow) || ($dateTimestamp1 = $day_after_tomorrow) || ($dateTimestamp1 = $today)) {
            // if checkin date is equal to today tomorrow or day after tomorrow add error message
            $errors['checkout_booking_period'] = "You have to reserve the place at least two days before the check in!";    
        }
        if ($dateTimestamp1 = $dateTimestamp2) {            
            $errors['checkout_booking_period'] = "check in date and check out date can not be same!";
        }
```

but these condition statements do not full fill the requirement.
eg: if the check in is a past and check out future date it says  **"check in date and check out date can not be same!"**
how can create the conditional statements to full fill the requirements I mentioned above?

Comment: if you return these dates from database, you can do this inside DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

1: You are using both string dates and timestamps, and you are comparing those in your conditional statements. The result of `date("m.d.y")` could be '09.07.14', a string you call `$today`, and you compare this to a timestamp resulting from `strtotime()`, like 2726372362. This causes the strange result. You should only use timestamps in the comparison.

2: You can always only set one value to `$errors['checkout_booking_period']`, but this is not reflected in your conditional statements. In theory it would be possible for more than one condition to be met. But you cannot store this in the `$errors` variable. In that case you can write code that executes more efficiently:

```
if ([condition1]) { [do something] }
elseif ([condition2]) { [do somthing else] }
elseif ([condition3]) { [do somthing else] } 
elseif ([condition4]) { [do somthing else] }
```

This way the code is done executing when the first condition is met. Surely it doesn't really matter much in this case, but it's better to learn efficient coding right from the start, and use it everywhere.

Comment: thanks for that. I've changed my code like this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1eca5b4ba5a6372f8438fbe5a6b587bc8956a27b
But as you see my date picker format is dd-mm-yy and still I'm getting strange result. where should I change this code?

Comment: Please read point 1 again, then echo the dates and timestamps before you compare them, and you'll see you still have the same problem. I like http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com I hadn't see it before.